# How to run a single query over all the tables in a user schema in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Let say I have tables `A,B,C,......,Z` and I want to count all the entries in the tables and combine the results like so:

```
SELECT 'A' AS A, count(*) from USER.A UNION  
. 
. 
.
SELECT 'J' AS J, count(*) from USER.J UNION
.
.
SELECT 'Z' AS 'Z' COUNT(*) from USER.Z
```

I want to avoid all above hassle. How can I do this in a smart way?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to do this by writing a query using the `user_tables` Meta information View and first time selecting text that is actually an sql query:

```
SELECT 'select '''||TABLE_NAME||''', count(*) from '||TABLE_NAME||'union all' FROM USER_TABLES
```

Running that in your query tool will produce a grid of rows that are actually sql queries in their own right. Copying them out of the results grid, pasting them into the query window (remove the trailing UNION ALL) and running them again produces data for each table

```
select 'a', count(*) from a union all
select 'b', count(*) from b union all ....
```

To get more involved and include column names, there's a USER_TAB_COLUMNS view that cites info about columns (e.g. You could write a query that generates queries that search any varchar columns for a particular value)

If you get really involved it can be cleaner to use placeholders in the string and REPLACE them:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(

  'select ''{o}.{t}'' as tname, ''{c}'' as cname 
   from {o}.{t} where 
    {c} like ''hello%'' or 
    {c} like ''goodbye%'' union all' 

  --to add more placeholders copy paste these lines 
  --and ensure there is the same number of REPLACE 
  --as there are numbers of lines 
  , '{t}', TABLE_NAME)
  , '{c}', COLUMN_NAME)
  , '{o}', OWNER)

FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR'
```

This is massively cleaner than starting and stopping your string all the time with || concatenation. I've deliberately uppercase the outer query and lowercase the inner query so you can tell which part is which

To add more placeholders, put additional REPLACE( at the top and copy paste in place the lines underneath that begin with a comma. Example copy `, '{t}', table_name)` paste and change to `, '{d}', data_type)` add another `REPLACE(` at the top and now you have a {d} placeholder you can use anywhere in the first string (the sql query pattern) to signify the data type

Comment: How can I specify the user schema. Ex if all the tables are under dmart and I have select the tables like so dmart.A, dmart,B etc.?

Comment: There is an ALL_TABLES / ALL_TAB_COLUMNS view set that isn't user specific. Se ether later advise I added about using placeholders. Put an additional placeholder for anything you want. Remember, all you're doing is building a string that happens to be an sql you can then run directly; you decide what data goes where, so do a `select * from ALL_TABLES` and have a think about the data you can see and which parts of it you want in an sql that produces the data you want. If you struggle to think in this "layer above" write the query first then convert it to placeholder form